# Want to show AdMob Interstitial ads in My Game after game over

Tags: android, admob, cocos2d-android

Hello I want to show ads (Interstitial) after each game over, but I'm facing some issues. Can someone please help me implement AdMob interstitial? The whole source code only has one class that extends activity. I know how to implement AdMob interstitial in app but I didn't use it in game before. Where should I add code and what is the code? Thank You.

This is my GameOverscreen code.

```
    public class GameOverScene extends CCLayer {
        //fields
        private SoundManager _soundMananger;
        private CCSprite _background;

        private CCMenu _menu;
        private CCMenu _restart;

        private CCLabel _yourScore; 
        private CCLabel _bestScore;
        //methods
        public static CCScene scene() {
            CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
            GameOverScene layer = new GameOverScene();      
            scene.addChild(layer);
            return scene;
        }

        public GameOverScene() {
            super();
            BeetleshotMainActivity.app.setHideAdView(false);
            _soundMananger = SoundManager.sharedSoundResourceManager();
            CGSize size = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize();
            float scaleX = size.width / 768.0f;
            float scaleY = size.height / 1024.0f;

            if (BeetleshotMainActivity.app._soundplay == true) {
                _soundMananger.bStopMenuSound();
                _soundMananger.bPlayMenuSound();
            }

            _background = CCSprite.sprite("Image/Gameover and Clear/Over_Bg.png");
            _background.setScaleX(scaleX);
            _background.setScaleY(scaleY);
            _background.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2));
            this.addChild(_background);

            CCMenuItemImage menuItem = CCMenuItemImage.item("Image/Gameover and Clear/MaiinNenu_n.png", "Image/Gameover and Clear/MaiinNenu_d.png", this, "menuAction");
            menuItem.setScaleX(scaleX);
            menuItem.setScaleY(scaleY);
            _menu = CCMenu.menu(menuItem);
            _menu.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(size.width*1.0f/2.0f, size.height*3.0f/10.0f));
            this.addChild(_menu);

            menuItem.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(menuItem.getPosition().x-50.0f, menuItem.getPosition().y));
            CCMoveBy dropTitle = CCMoveBy.action(1.5f, CGPoint.ccp(50.0f, 0.0f));
            CCEaseBounceOut easeDrop = CCEaseBounceOut.action(dropTitle);
            menuItem.runAction(easeDrop);

            CCMenuItemImage restartItem = CCMenuItemImage.item("Image/Gameover and Clear/Restart_n.png", "Image/Gameover and Clear/Restart_d.png", this, "restartAction");
            restartItem.setScaleX(scaleX);
            restartItem.setScaleY(scaleY);
            _restart = CCMenu.menu(restartItem);
            _restart.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(size.width/2.0f, (float) (size.height*4.2f/10.0f)));
            this.addChild(_restart);

            restartItem.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(restartItem.getPosition().x+50.0f, restartItem.getPosition().y));
            dropTitle = CCMoveBy.action(1.5f, CGPoint.ccp(-50.0f, 0.0f));
            easeDrop = CCEaseBounceOut.action(dropTitle);
            restartItem.runAction(easeDrop);


    //      CCMenuItemImage shareI = CCMenuItemImage.item("Image/MainMenu/share.png", "Image/MainMenu/Share.png", this, "Share");
            fb.setScaleX(scaleX);
            fb.setScaleY(scaleY);
            _restart = CCMenu.menu(shareI);
            _restart.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(size.width/2.0f, (float) (size.height*1.5f/10.0f)));
            this.addChild(_restart);

            shareI.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(restartItem.getPosition().x+50.0f, restartItem.getPosition().y));
            dropTitle = CCMoveBy.action(1.5f, CGPoint.ccp(-160.0f, 0.0f));
            easeDrop = CCEaseBounceOut.action(dropTitle);
            shareI.runAction(easeDrop);

I wan to handle the click.. How do i Do that? I want to show createChooser dialog when user press on the share icon.

            Intent iShare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        iShare.setType("text/plain");
        iShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Download The Game");
        iShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Get The Game"+" "+"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jdtfans.jdtfootballkickers");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(iShare,"Share Via"));


Above code i want to use when user press share icon. How do i do that?


            float scaleFactor = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize().height/1024 * 2.3f;

            _yourScore = CCLabel.makeLabel(String.format("%d", BeetleshotMainActivity.app._score), CGSize.make(120.0f*scaleFactor, 60.0f*scaleFactor), TextAlignment.CENTER, "Font/Imagica.ttf", 24.0f*scaleFactor);_yourScore.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(size.width*1.32f/2.0f, (float) (size.height*1.12/2.0f)));

            this.addChild(_yourScore);
            _yourScore.setColor(ccColor3B.ccBLUE);

            // add this 
            _bestScore = CCLabel.makeLabel(String.format("%d", GameScene._hScoreValue), CGSize.make(120.0f*scaleFactor, 60.0f*scaleFactor), TextAlignment.CENTER, "Font/Imagica.ttf", 24.0f*scaleFactor);_bestScore.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(size.width*1.32f/2.0f, (float) (size.height*1/2.0f)));

            this.addChild(_bestScore);
            _bestScore.setColor(ccColor3B.ccBLUE);
            //
            switch(BeetleshotMainActivity.app._locationLevel) {
                case 1:
                    BeetleshotMainActivity.app._level = 1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    BeetleshotMainActivity.app._level = 2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    BeetleshotMainActivity.app._level = 3;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            int currentScore = BeetleshotMainActivity.app._score;   
            BeetleshotMainActivity.app._score = 0;      

            if (BeetleshotMainActivity.app._location == 1) {
                switch(BeetleshotMainActivity.app._locationLevel) {
                    case 1:
                        BeetleshotMainActivity.app.loadScore("score1");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        BeetleshotMainActivity.app.loadScore("score2");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        BeetleshotMainActivity.app.loadScore("score3");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (currentScore > BeetleshotMainActivity.app._score) {
                BeetleshotMainActivity.app._score = currentScore;

                if (BeetleshotMainActivity.app._location == 1) {
                    switch(BeetleshotMainActivity.app._locationLevel) {
                        case 1:
                            BeetleshotMainActivity.app.saveScore("score1");
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            BeetleshotMainActivity.app.saveScore("score2");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            BeetleshotMainActivity.app.saveScore("score3");
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void menuAction(Object sender) {
            if (BeetleshotMainActivity.app._soundplay == true)
                _soundMananger.ePlayButtonClickSound();     
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(CCFadeTransition.transition(0.7f, MenuScene.scene()));
        }

        public void restartAction(Object sender) {
            if (BeetleshotMainActivity.app._soundplay == true)
                _soundMananger.ePlayButtonClickSound();     
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(CCFadeTransition.transition(0.7f, GameScene.scene()));
        }

    }




This is my only activity class that i have in my project.


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            app = this;
            mContext = this;
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            ccMacros.CCLOG("BeetleShot Game", "OnCreate");

            RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            mGLSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);

            // Create the adView
            adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, ADMOB_PUBLISH_ID);

            // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
            adView.setAdListener(this);
            // Add the adView to it
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            adView.setLayoutParams(params);

            layout.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
            layout.addView(adView);
            ////


            // create the interstitial
            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "**********");

            // load interstitialAd
            Ads.loadInterstitialAd(interstitial);

            // set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
            interstitial.setAdListener(this);
            setContentView(layout);

            CCDirector.sharedDirector().attachInView(mGLSurfaceView);
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().setDisplayFPS(false);
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().setAnimationInterval(1.0f / 30);

            CCTexture2D.setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat(Config.ARGB_8888);

            _soundplay = true;
            _playerSound = true;
            _controlShow = false;
            _playerPos = 1;
            _level = 1;
            _firstBonus = 0;
            _secondBonus = 0;
            _thirdBonus = 0;
            _locationLevel = 1;

            CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(LogoScene.scene());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();       
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().onResume();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause(); 
            SoundManager.sharedSoundResourceManager()._soundEngine.pauseSound();
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();      
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().end();
        SoundManager.releaseSoundResourceManager();
        }

        public void loadScore (String filename) {
            try {
                ccMacros.CCLOG("file reading", "reading scores from " + filename);
                FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput(filename);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
                char[] buf = new char[6];
                isr.read(buf);
                _score = Integer.parseInt(new String(buf).trim());
                isr.close();
                fIn.close();
                ccMacros.CCLOG("file reading result", "" + _score);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        public void saveScore (String filename) {
            try {
                ccMacros.CCLOG("file writing", "writing scores to " + filename);
                FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
                osw.write("" + _score);
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        public CGPoint getBufPlayerPos() {
            return _m_playerPos;
        }

        public void setBufPlayerPos (CGPoint rpos) {
            _m_playerPos = rpos;
        }

        // Admob Setting


        public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Log.d(TAG, "+++++++++++++ New admob has received! ++++++++++++++");
        }


        Handler handler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if(msg.what == 0) {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);         
                }
            }
        };

        public void setHideAdView(boolean bHide) {
            if(bHide) {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
            else {
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);            
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the Parent Class "CCLayer" an activity?

Comment: No...its not an activity

Comment: You can you define an interface use it's listener object to invoke the ads. Post the underlying activity so I can answer your question well. Thanks

Comment: May I know the class that extends Activity? CCLayer?

Comment: CCLayer is built-in class of cocos2d..I cannot see the methods of it..

Comment: Ok! I've provided an answer. Use that and let's see how it goes. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, a facade design pattern is used to achieve this but since you already have access to the activity's context in your Scene class via BeetleshotMainActivity.app, you can use that as follows:

In the Main Activity class, define a method to show the interstitial ad. You can use a handler as you did with the setAdView() method, but using the runOnUiThread is much simpler:

```
public void showInterstitialAd() {  
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (interstitial != null && interstitial.isReady())
            interstitial.show();
        }        
     });
```

}

Then in your game over constructor, just show the interstitial ad as follows:

```
 public GameOverScene() {
        super();
        BeetleshotMainActivity.app.setHideAdView(false);
         BeetleshotMainActivity.app.showInterstitialAd();
           -----
           ------
}
```

The onDismissScreen callback method is called when the user returns to the activity after clicking the ad. So you can "reload" the interstital ad when it's called so ads will be shown on subsequent game overs:

```
 public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 // create the interstitial
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "***********");

        // load interstitialAd
        Ads.loadInterstitialAd(interstitial);

        // set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
        interstitial.setAdListener(this);
   }
```

Comment: The method run() of type new Runnable(){} must override a superclass method... I get this error..

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: You helped me a lot..Thank You so much..Hope to get help from you in future..Thanks.!You are great.

Comment: I am facing one issue that is the ad is just shown for once after game over...can you help me with that.?

Comment: Don't get you! I believe showing once is the right way. Or you mean on subsequent game overs, the ad isn't shown.

Comment: Yes. I want to the ad to be shown after every game over...but now i can see only once and later i dont see ad after game over.

Comment: I've updated my answer(last paragraph). Try it out! BTW, don't post your ad unit ids on the internet. Someone can use them and get you banned. Replace with a mask - *****.

Comment: Thank You for your help.... Really Good Guy..Helped me to solve two problem and i have learnt something from you. (y).Can i have your email address?If you have no problem.

Comment: Thank you.i can vote up from this account because vote up requires 15 reputation at least.but dont worry i will do that from another acxount

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287786/photo-upload-to-google-drive-via-android-app


Hi can you help me with this?

Comment: Sorry I haven't worked with google drive before...only dropbox

Comment: No! I usually prefer writing my own framework, but I know Libgdx

Comment: Hi I want to handle a click (share Icon) on Game over screen. How can i do that? Can you please help me? I have updated the Game over screen code above.

Comment: Please post a new question and notify me. Also, let's refrain from  long discussions via comments

Comment: Ok. I am posting new question.

Comment: Hi I have posted a new question .Here is the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322721/handling-a-share-button-click-on-android-game

Comment: Great! Sorry I was asleep. I've answered it :)